# Different options to convert brick wall outlet box to junction box with more outlets

Tags: electrical, brick, junction-box

I have a dedicated 20A circuit that comes into my kitchen area as a duplex outlet:
[image: outlet on brick wall]

During the upcoming kitchen remodel this circuit will likely be the best one to provide power to the very nearby fridge plus a couple of outlets.

That means putting in a junction box instead of the outlet box and running a couple of conduits from it, if I understand the code correctly.

It would be very desirable not to do any unnecessary cutting into the brick wall and while I'm not a huge fan of the electric conduit on top of brick wall look, luckily, this it pretty low (about a foot off the floor) so there may be ways to make it less prominent.

Here's the current outlet:
[image: inside outlet box]

The wires are coming up in BX/flexible armored cable if that matters.  I'd like to avoid the need to increase the brick opening, but I'm not sure if the space is large enough for a junction box of the size I would need and how the wires can come out to then go along the brick (I've seen extension junction boxes but I'm not certain this is the sort of application they are meant for).

Are there other ways to achieve the same goal with minimal "disturbance" of the brick wall?

Comment: A kitchen needs *so much* electrical service, that the answer is "don't put a kitchen along a brick wall".  Best you can hope for is keep any kitchen countertops away from the brick area and have it be an empty wall, but even there you need a receptacle within 6' of any point horizontally.   This could end up being an ugly mess of surface conduit,   Don't take my word on it, check with your architect.

Comment: This isn't the only circuit for the kitchen and the kitchen is not along the brick wall so I don't know where your comment came from.

Comment: Just to clarify - this wall is perpendicular to the wall the kitchen is on but the fridge is 90 to that wall at the logical end of the kitchen U - and an office area is going to be on this side of the room.  Turning this circuit into one that powers the fridge and feeds outlets to the office area and maybe another next to the fridge will take the pressure off of the three circuits that come up on the wall that the main part of kitchen is at.   Having said that, I'm not still not sure why conduit below counter level would be potentially an ugly mess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This *is* one of things extension boxes are for

Your usecase is one of several that extension boxes are meant for -- you'll either want to use a standard one-gang metal extension box with THHN in EMT running to surface mounted one gang boxes for the new receptacles, or a *surface raceway* (sometimes called 'wiremold' after Legrand's brand name for the stuff, not to be confused with a product Legrand calls "cordmate" that is only intended for signal cables) extension box ("starter box") along with matching raceway and surface mount receptacle boxes, with either NM or THHN run in the raceways.

An example of the latter is shown below.

[image: metal wiremold starter box]

Comment: is this the same thing I see referred to in various videos as "starter box"?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky -- yep, that's what you're after for the starting point of the surface raceway run